# Mouse location in java

Tags: java, frame-rate

I am developing a first person shooter in Java and I want to implement controls in which movement of the mouse rotates the player. However in Java, I can only get mouse coordinates by using `MouseListener` events, so the coordinates will stop changing once the mouse cursor leaves the monitor edge and I will be unable to turn the player's view.

Any tips/suggestions on how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: .. but you'll also know that the mouse _isn't_ moving, right?

Comment: @sarnold: I think the point is that the *mouse* might still be moving but the *cursor* isn't.

Comment: @Greg: Ah! Back in my Quake days, if you moved the mouse two pixels off center, you'd rotate very slowly but continuously -- and if you moved it to the edge, you'd spin very quickly (and also continuously). Since moving only when the mouse moves sounds like it requires a lot of desk space, I didn't give that option much though. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some games, on every mouse movement event the cursor is moved back to the middle of the screen, and the view moves with the corresponding magnitude and direction of the mouse event.  You can get that vector by calculating the offset of the cursor position to the center of the screen prior to centering the cursor.  To move the cursor back to the center of the screen you can try using the [java.awt.Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class.

Since you're building a first person shooter, you'll probably want to hide the center locked cursor, and draw your own crosshair where the player is intending to aim.  That will also involve keeping track of where the cursor *should* be based on the running total of previous mouse movement events.

If you want to achieve behaviour where the view will continue moving relative to the starting position of the mouse (even once the mouse has stopped moving), you could keep a moving sum of all the previous mouse movement vectors, and move the view correspondingly once every frame.  However, this probably applies more to something like a flight simulator than a first person shooter.

Comment: It just so happens, I did the exact same thing while waiting for an answer. I didn't know games actually did it that way. Thanks

Comment: Great stuff, you're welcome!  This is usually called a mouse/cursor/pointer lock.

Answer (score 5):

I tried using a `java.awt.Robot` as AerandiR suggests, but there were a couple of problems I ran into, and it's possible other people will run into them as well, so I will elaborate.

If your goal is to keep the cursor in one position (preferably the center of the screen), then you will want to call something like `robot.mouseMove(width/2, height/2);` at the end of your `mouseMoved()` method. With this implementation, every time the mouse is moved off center, the `Robot` will move it back to the center.

However, when the `Robot` re-centers the mouse, the player will turn back to where it was. In effect, the player will stutter between the original position and a turned position.

To fix this, instead of defining how far your player turns on the difference between where the mouse is now and where it was, define it as the distance from the center.

Like so: `turnAmountX += e.getX() - width/2;`

Now, if the `Robot` re-centers the mouse, `e.getX() - width/2` will always yield zero.

Recap:

```
    void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        turnAmountX += e.getX() - width/2;
        turnAmountY += e.getY() - height/2;
        robot.mouseMove(this.getLocationOnScreen().x + width/2, 
            this.getLocationOnScreen().y + height/2;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the extra information I needed and couldn't find anywhere.. Genius.